# How can I set path to save image uploaded? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, image-uploading

My method to upload file in laravel like this :

```
private function addPhoto(UploadedFile $photo, $fileName)
{
    dd(public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img');
    $destinationPath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img';
    $photo->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
}
```

The result of `dd(public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img');` like this :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img

But I want to change it

So, I want to save image uploaded in here :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\storage\temp

How can I save the image in storage folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exact same way, but replace [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-public-path) with [`storage_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path). This will link to the storage folder for this application.

```
$destinationPath = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'temp';
```

All path helpers can be found in [the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#paths).

Answer (score 1):

Use `storage_path`.

```
private function addPhoto(UploadedFile $photo, $fileName)
{
    $photo->move(storage_path('temp'), $fileName);
}
```